# PHP form with upload option - allow no upload

Tags: php, forms

I'm really not great at PHP, so bear with me. I have a form on one of my sites and it allows the user to upload a file. The problem is that if the user doesn't upload a file, the form can't be submitted.

The entire form code is wrapped with an if conditional to see if the files are set and I think that's what's causing it. This is how the code starts:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $name => $file) {
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
        if (!in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)) {
            die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
        }
        array_push($files, $file);
    }
```

Then it sets the conditions for the uploads:

```
// boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    

    // preparing attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++) {
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'], "rb");
        $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $files[$x]['name'];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
    // send
```

**How would I add logic that would allow the form to be submitted without uploading a file?**

Comment: There is nothing which prevents the submission of the form, the code only checks if something exists... (PHP can't prevent that anyway, that would be possible only via Javascript)

Comment: _"The problem is that if the user doesn't upload a file, the form can't be submitted."_ - would a more precise description be that the form is submitted, but there is no result? That code wouldn't stop the form from being submitted, it merely wouldn't do anything. If so, _"The entire form code is wrapped with an if conditional to see if the files are set and I think that's what's causing it."_ is a correct observation.

Comment: Instead of wrapping it in a condition about the files, wrap it in a condition about the submit button.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: @Barmar if I change that condition, the code would still make sure that there is a file that has been set for upload, correct?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Thanks for that clarification

Comment: No, that's the whole point. You want to allow the form submission even without a file, right?

Comment: If there are no files, the `foreach` loop won't do anything, but the rest of the form processing will still work.

Comment: @Barmar so just changing the first line to what you posted would work?

Comment: Assuming you have a button `<input type="submit" name="submit">`. If the name is something else, change the `$_POST` variable accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231192/discussion-between-al-lemieux-and-barmar).